# Determine national carrier code using libphonenumber

Tags: java, phone-number, libphonenumber

I need to determine the national carrier code (not the country code) of any phone number, using [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) Java SDK. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help your case - `PhoneNumberToCarrierMapper`

- [com.google.i18n.phonenumber.PhoneNumberToCarrierMapper](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.googlecode.libphonenumber/carrier/latest/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberToCarrierMapper.html)

In the `PhoneNumberToCarrierMapper` class there is a method:

```
String getNameForValidNumber(PhoneNumber number, Locale languageCode)
```

This should give your the carrier code.
You can see the source code of that method in the related GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/blob/332e0465bed1c32d4e863e6616e469884ed7f882/java/carrier/src/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberToCarrierMapper.java#L73).

Comment: I don't have that class. I'm using libphonenumber-7.7.5.jar

Comment: You need carrier jar - you can use from here , http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/libphonenumber/carrier/1.10/

Comment: Worked perfectly... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

libphonenumber-8.13.6 doesn't seem to come packaged with PhoneNumberToCarrierMapper class. The import will not work for `com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberToCarrierMapper`

I had to add a separate jar to my build path to get this class to successfully import. If you are using maven, you would just need to add a new dependency to your pom file.

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/libphonenumber/carrier/